# Is It Idiomatic To Use C++ Exception Handling Only For "Real" Errors?

Tags: c++, exception, idioms

I learned about the `try/catch` block awhile ago. From what I understand, this is used to handle "Real" errors like runtime errors. Instead, I used it to handle incorrect sign in attempts here, even though it's not really needed:

```
void signIn(std::vector<User>& userVect, int& index, bool& isLoggedIn)
{
    std::string userNameSearchKey;
    std::string pass;
    int passwordRetry = 0;
    int userRetry = 0;
    bool keepSearching = true;
    bool userFound = false;

    while (!userFound && userRetry < 3 && userNameSearchKey != "b")
    {
        try
        {
            if (userRetry >= 3)
            {
                throw 2;
            }
            std::cout << "\nEnter a username, or 'b' to go back" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Username: ";
            std::cin >> userNameSearchKey;
            if (userNameSearchKey == "b")
            {
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "Password: ";
            std::cin >> pass;
            for (int i = 0; i < userVect.size(); i++)
            {
                if (userNameSearchKey == userVect[i].getUserName())
                {
                    userFound = true;
                    if (pass == userVect[i].getPassword())
                    {
                        std::cout << "\nWelcome " << userVect[i].getUserName();     // Welcomes the user
                        index = i;          // When this function ends
                        isLoggedIn = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw 1;
                    }                   
                }
            }
            if (!userFound && userNameSearchKey != "b")
            {
                throw 1;
            }
        }
        catch(int x)
        {
            if (x == 1)
            {
                std::cout << "\nError " << x << ": Incorrect username or password." << std::endl;
                userRetry++;
                if (userRetry >= 3)
                {
                    std::cout << "Too many incorrect attempts. Going back to the main menu." << std::endl;
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that the code is just an illustration of the point I'm making: The function works fine and it does its job, but I could also get the same effect without `try/catch` and `throw`. Is it more idiomatic to reserve exception handling for actual errors?

Comment: What do you mean "actual errors"? Errors are things that happen when you don't want them to happen. You can use `try/catch` blocks to handle those things that happen when you don't want them to.

Comment: @Filip : "Real" errors like runtime errors.

Comment: When you think that a runtime error could occur use a try/catch block. Again errors are not "real" or "fake", errors are things that you don't want to happen. You can use try/catch blocks to either fix them, ignore them or print a message notifying the user that he did something wrong. You should use them often because they help "guide" your program to the correct direction and do exaxtly what you want it to do.

Comment: @Filip: You asked "What do you mean "actual errors"?"

Comment: [Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222)

Comment: @L.F. : Hmm thanks for this